# build library from source with Anaconda with cmake, cuda and VS requirements

Tags: python, cmake, anaconda

I am trying to install [this library](https://github.com/DavidDiazGuerra/gpuRIR) in a conda environment.

Requirements:

- `Cmake` 3.12 or above
- CUDA (10 or above if includes cuRAND)
- Python 3

I have created an environment in anaconda with installed `cudatoolkit` 10.1 and `cmake`, and ran the command `pip install https://github.com/DavidDiazGuerra/gpuRIR/zipball/master`. However, I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
      Generator

        Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

      could not find any instance of Visual Studio
```

I also tried to install CUDA on my machine and add its location to my env variable. (I tried both env variables in windows console and anaconda environment.) After this error, I tried to install Visual Studio Build tools 2019, but still received the same error.

Could someone help me or point me to some useful resources? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion